# Example where the product of two integrable functions is not integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried searching through the site for examples but to not avail. I was thinking of constructing $f$ and $g$ such that $fg= \frac{1}{x}$, but that proved to be more difficult than I thought. Any thoughts?

Comment: $f=g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ should do nicely.

Comment: @Hugo Not defined on $[0,1]$...

Comment: @DonThousand By the question I assumed that we could put f(0) = g(0) = 0 and look for measurable functions, but maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: Since the OP states the attempt to find a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ such that $fg(x)=1/x$ which isn’t defined at $0$, the example given by Hugo seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you meant *Riemann*-integrable functions (and not meaning improper integrals), there is no such pair of functions. Both $f$ and $g$ are bounded  and, for each of them, the set of points at whcih it is discontinuous has Lebesgue measure $0$. So, $fg$ als has those two preperties, and therefore it is Riemann-inegrable.

Comment: @jeb2 just FYI the more common definitions of an integral are Riemann and Lebesgue. The ones with a gauge are less so

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\chi_{(0,1]}(x)$

Comment: Fair warning: this function isn't technically Riemann integrable. It is improperly integrable, however.

Comment: @CameronWilliams No where in the question is there mentioned 'Riemann integrable'

Comment: It's not an attack on you at all. It's a perfectly fine answer without extra information. I only made the comment in case OP missed that and was working in the Riemann/Darboux setting only (and not permitting improper integrals).

Comment: There is indeed no mention of Riemann integrable, but did you guess OP would be talking about the Henstock-Kurzweil integral? :) Or at least I suspect that's what OP means by the mention of a gauge. In which case this example is correct